# In-App Purchase... Can I do this?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription

I'm building an app that will provide users with an evolving directory of companies in their local area (location-based) that manufacture green/sustainable products.  I want companies to be able to add themselves to the app by purchasing a subscription using in-app purchase.  This would be a 1 year subscription.

Just read this in the iOS Standard Agreement:  2.3   Content and services may be offered through the In-App Purchase API on a subscription basis (e.g., subscriptions to newspapers and magazines).  Rentals of content, services or functionality through the In-App Purchase API are not allowed (e.g., use of particular content may not be restricted to a pre-determined, limited period of time).

If the service is only for a year, does this preclude me from doing the above?  Anybody have any insight on any of this?  I'd appreciate your input - I can't get any info from Apple.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are not allowed to do that. As you really cannot restrict who subscribes for a year – it might be any user – you probably cannot offer this. The IAP doesn't provide any content or service to the user other that a listing. As you probably need an external data source (e.g. a web application) I would suggest moving the subscription there. This is just my opinion and I am no lawyer so I might be completely wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it. See the image below. You just have to choose the right option.
You can find it itunesConnect in the app detail section.
For your case I suggest Consumable is appropriate and have to maintain a check that wether its been a year or not since the last magazine purchase or what so ever your scenario is.
[image]

Comment: This is great.  Thank you yunas.  Can a 'consumable'-type IAP be a renewable 'membership' like the one described above?  (I know I'd have to handle membership reminders on the server-side) - but do you know if this is an acceptable use of 'consumable' type IAP?  Thank you very much for your input.

Comment: Can a 'consumable'-type IAP be a renewable 'membership' like the one described above? => ANSWER =>     YES , for example in games when we buy some coins and we utilize all of them then we have to re-buy to play it again same is what you are saying like you have bought coins that will work for years... but when the year ends you have to recharge/ rebuy the coins... so refill or rebuy, then why not !